# Composer Installation Error asking to remove from system path

Tags: php, installation, xampp, composer-php

[composer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lslKO.png)

I am getting error while trying to `install Composer`.

The error is

> Remove from the System path: c:\windows\system32.

Please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase: Just FYI, the question has an accepted answer since quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open CMD as Administrator type > `where composer`

It will show where your global composer file is.

If this the error you will

> Remove from the System path: c:\windows\system32

find a `composer.bat` file in that directory. Delete that file and run installation again. Hope this fix your problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

same here but, trying to uninstall/reinstall composer but after uninstallation and clicking the composer installer i had the same prob..

I got the installer FIXED  after a computer restart so that the uninstall will be complete and "system variables" will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the problem is, but I ran into the same problem. On a hunch, I tried reinstalling composer again. When asked to choose the PhP engine, I chose PhP 5.6, which I understand is still available on all wampp / xampp installations.
That seemed to do the trick. Why 5.6 is working but 7.3 is not working I have no idea. Furthermore, I feel there is a better solution to this. Unfortunately I don't know it, but at least you can get working if that is the right solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem
i resolve by
delete *php.exe* in c:\windows\system32